# Python/Tkinter: How to reduce the size of the expanded frames to their first positions?

Tags: python, tkinter

According to the below codes; when the application is first run, two buttons display on the screen. If the user click one of the buttons, the frame is expanded and new buttons can be seen. If the user click the new buttons, another frame is expanded and new buttons can be seen again.

For example if the user first clicks the **"English"** button, the **"Expand"** button can be seen. And if the user click the **"Expand"** button, **"Data"** button can be seen. After that if the user click the **"Turkish"** button, the **"Expand"** button changes to **"Genişlet"** but the **"Data"** button still keeps on displaying, finally if the user clicks the **"Genişlet"** button, the **"Data"** button changes to **"Veri"**.

But the above operation is not what i want to do. I want to change the **"Veri"** or **"Data"** buttons by clicking the **"English"** or **"Turkish"** buttons.

So, in order to do that, which parts of the codes i should modify? Thank you in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.b1 = tk.Button(master=self, text="Turkish", width=20)
        self.b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.b2 = tk.Button(master=self, text="English", width=20)
        self.b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.f1 = tk.Frame(master=master)
        self.f1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.f2 = tk.Frame(master=master)
        self.f2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.f3 = tk.Frame(master=self.f1)
        self.f4 = tk.Frame(master=self.f1)

        self.b3 = tk.Button(master=self.f3, text="Genişlet")
        self.b3.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.b4 = tk.Button(master=self.f4, text="Expand")
        self.b4.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.f5 = tk.Frame(master=self.f2)
        self.f6 = tk.Frame(master=self.f2)

        self.b5 = tk.Button(master=self.f5, text="Veri")
        self.b5.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.b6 = tk.Button(master=self.f6, text="Data")
        self.b6.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.configure_buttons()

    @staticmethod
    def activate(frame, parent):
        for child in parent:
            child.grid_forget()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def configure_buttons(self):
        self.b1.configure(command=lambda: self.activate(self.f3, self.f1.winfo_children()))
        self.b2.configure(command=lambda: self.activate(self.f4, self.f1.winfo_children()))
        self.b3.configure(command=lambda: self.activate(self.f5, self.f2.winfo_children()))
        self.b4.configure(command=lambda: self.activate(self.f6, self.f2.winfo_children()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = App(master=root)
    frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should add a command to the language buttons that calls a function that will change the the text variable of the buttons to change between predefined text for each language. Should be easy to implement.

Comment: Ok, i will try to do that. But the language buttons have already commands, can we give the second command to them?

Comment: Using a function to change the text will allow you to have less code as well. It will reduce the number of buttons because you only need one button per section and just change the text on that button :)

Comment: I removed the button name then I added a function to change the text to both "Turkish" and "English" buttons. But it's just displaying it's english name. As if it only displays the second defined variable.

Comment: By the way i have just solved the problem with your suggestion, thank you again.

Comment: Cool. I am still going to post an answer. It might be different than what you did and could be useful.

Comment: Yes, when you are free, please let me see your suggestion. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that keeps the functionality you currently have while being able to apply the language changes using `textvariable` and `stringVar()`

There is a better way I am sure but for this simple program this should suffice.

I created two variables set to a `StringVar()` The first 2 buttons are linked to a function/method that will change the strings for each stringVar to reflect the language choice.

I also created some place holder variables to use until the other buttons needed to be created. Let me know what you think of this option.

Update: I added a menu that will remove all the buttons except for the starting 2 buttons. Effectively a restart.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.btn1_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.btn1_text.set("Expand")
        self.btn2_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.btn2_text.set("Data")
        self.second_frame = "None"
        self.btn2 = "None"
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.top_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ew")

        self.turkish_button = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="Turkish", width=20, command = lambda: self.change_lang_and_add_btn1("turkish"))
        self.turkish_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.english_button = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="English", width=20, command = lambda: self.change_lang_and_add_btn1("english"))
        self.english_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = self.menu)
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff = 0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.file_menu)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = "Reset", command = self.reset_buttons)

    def change_lang_and_add_btn1(self, choice):
        if choice == "english":
            self.btn1_text.set("Expand")
            self.btn2_text.set("Data")
        if choice == "turkish":
            self.btn1_text.set("Genişlet")
            self.btn2_text.set("Veri")

        if self.second_frame == "None":
            self.second_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
            self.second_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
            self.btn1 = tk.Button(self.second_frame, textvariable = self.btn1_text, width=20, command = lambda: self.add_btn2())
            self.btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    def add_btn2(self):
        if self.btn2 == "None":
            self.btn2 = tk.Button(self.second_frame, textvariable = self.btn2_text, width=20)
            self.btn2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    def reset_buttons(self):
        if self.second_frame != "None":
            self.second_frame.destroy()
            self.second_frame = "None"
            self.btn2 = "None"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = App(root)
    frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: @dilde olupbiten: Do you want to be able to remove the expanded buttons by clicking the last button or do you want something like a reset button? or a reset menu option?

Comment: Great, it works. I need to review your codes and make exercises with them. Your method is different than i choosed. If you want to see, i will post mine.

Comment: Oh, (if you are available now) yes a reset button can be appropriate. By the way thank you very much.

Comment: @dildeolupbiten: I have made the changes to the code so you can have a menu option for a restart/reset. You can also created another button that links to the reset function if you wish. In order to to this I had to put the created buttons into a frame then destroy that frame when it was time to reset.

Comment: Thank you very much again, it works too. I will review these codes.